# Translatable dropdown menu

Tags: craft3, field, drop-down

Does anyone know how to make the dropdown field translatable?

I'm working on a site which has both English and German languages, but whenever I set up a dropdown field it only ever appears in English and I don't have an option for the German version.

EDIT: I'm needing this to work as a dropdown on the German site also and not through templating `{{ "word" | t }}` as I need the client to have total control of this feature.

Any help would be appreciated — thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the dropdown menu field in CraftCMS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does it per default:

```
public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
{
    return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('_includes/forms/select', [
        'name' => $this->handle,
        'value' => $value,
        'options' => $this->translatedOptions(), //<-- here are your translated options
    ]);
}
```

But you need to insert your translations into your translation files for the `site` category

```
protected function translatedOptions(): array
{
    $translatedOptions = [];

    if ($this->options) {
        foreach ($this->options as $option) {
            $translatedOptions[] = [
                'label' => Craft::t('site', $option['label']),
                'value' => $option['value']
            ];
        }
    }

    return $translatedOptions;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay — I have a translation file already set up but wanted the client to have total control over what the German options would be. Guessing the translation file is the only option really?

Comment: No - if you want to change the translation method, you can use a database table as well https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/way-for-clients-to-edit-translation-files-in-control-panel

Comment: Brilliant — I'll have a look into that. Thanks!